# How to get the latest data from Angular Service?

Tags: angular, angular-services

If I'm trying to get a data from a service, which is updated from another component, how could I do that?

Below it's an example to describe what my problem is, though it is a bad example.

If I had a service called userInfoService that stores the user names only.

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class UserInfoService {
  userNames?: string[];
}
```

And a component: `SignUpPageComponent` updates the userName

```js
@Component...
export class SignUpStepComponent {
  constructor(private userInfoService: UserInfoService){}
  
  // do something and...
  this.userInfoService.userNames = [Tim];
}
```

How to get the userNames in another component: ReviewAccountStepComponent? Or to be specific, when should ReviewAccountStepComponent call the function to get the latest names?

Both the SignUpStepComponent and ReviewAccountStepComponent are at the same level, if that matters.

```js
@Component...
export class ReviewAccountStepComponent {
  customerNames: string[];
  constructor(private userInfoService: UserInfoService){}
  
  ngOnInit() { // won't work
    this.customerNames = this.userInfoService.userNames;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using a Service is great. But instead of storing the value in a variable, you can push it to a Subject and subscribe to this Subject from the other component

Answer (score 0):

No, It does not work like that, you need to store data in an observable ( a Subject) in your service.

Now the second component should subscribe to this observable in ngOnInt.

The problem which I understand from your scenario is that you store a list in a service. and when the second component loads, it will read this data only once on ngOnInt.
Now whenever this list is modified by first component altough it is updated in the service. The second component will never be notified of the changes since it read the list only once when this component created

With an observable you can observe to these data changes dynamically,

Also let me add an example to make it more clear.
[Github](https://github.com/entitylabs/observable-service-angular.git)

Here is the service with the subject that will be observed by the second component

file name: `data.service.ts`

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class DataService {
    
      data:Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
    
    
      constructor() { }
    
      submit(val:string){
      
        this.data.next(val);
      }
    }
```

Here is first component:

`component1.component.css`

```css
    .comp1{
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 20px;
    }
```

`component1.component.html`

```html
    <div class="comp1">
        <input [(ngModel)]= "dataField" />
        <button (click)="onsubmit()">submit</button>
    </div>
```

`component1.component.ts`

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { DataService } from '../data.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-component1',
      templateUrl: './component1.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./component1.component.css']
    })
    export class Component1Component implements OnInit {
    
      dataField:string='';
      constructor(private dataService:DataService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    
      onsubmit(){
    
        this.dataService.submit(this.dataField);
      }
    }
```

here is second component

`comp2.component.css`

```css
    .comp2{
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 20px; }
    
    .received{
        color:red }
```

`comp2.component.html`

```html
    <div class="comp2">
        <div>
            <label>
                showing data from first component via service
            </label>
        </div>
        
    
        <div class="received">
            <label>
                {{receivedvalue}}
            </label>
        </div>
       
    </div>
```

`comp2.component.ts`

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { DataService } from '../data.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-comp2',
      templateUrl: './comp2.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./comp2.component.css']
    })
    export class Comp2Component implements OnInit {
    
      receivedvalue:any;
    
      constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
    
        this.dataService.data.subscribe(data=>{
          this.receivedvalue=data;
        });
      }
    
    }
```

the `app-component.html`

```html
    <app-component1></app-component1>
    <app-comp2></app-comp2>
```

Do not forget to import `FormsModule` in app.module.ts as we are using two way binding in first component on the input field

And the output would look like this communication b/w components happening via service using subject

[image]

Comment: Yes! this is what i need! 
After diving into some real-world cases, I found out the subscribe/observable might be the solution to my problem.